# Tunneling & Bypass proxy

Tags: proxy, tunnel

are there any software for ubuntu to tunneling/bypass proxy (HTTP/S, SOCK4/5). Like "Proxifier" on windows ?

Comment: You could try the easy to use GUI tool [GrrProxy](https://github.com/Cadogan/GrrProxy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the ever-popular PuTTY (http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) is available through the repositories.

To install it run:

```
sudo apt-get install putty
```

To set up tunneling it is quite easy. 
Open PuTTY
Enter the IP address of the server you want to tunnel to (where 255.255.255.255 is in the image)
[image: Enter the IP address of the server you wish to tunnel to]

After entering the IP address, click on the 'Tunnels' tab under SSH.

Now enter the port you want the connections to go over on the source port and set your localhost at that specified port as the destination and click 'Add'

[image: Click on the tunnels tab]

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use putty as a dynamic proxy to go across the firewall, just select "Dynamic" and type any available source port you wish(ie. 9050), then press "Add". Things get done :D

Go to your system proxy setting(ONLY configure in your browser if you want it to be the browser's proxy) , only set the socks v5 proxy as 127.0.0.1:yourport (ie. 127.0.0.1:9050)

---

*Wanna use it to break the firewall in Browsers, then continue reading the information as below otherwise that's all.*

If you are using firefox, type `about:config` in the address bar, then search "remote_dns", set the value to *True*

If you are using chrome, just install the "Proxy SwitchySharp" extention, remote dns resolve is used by default.

Have fun with your newly setup proxy and have fun bypassing the firewall between your PC and your target hosts.

Comment: actually, it's very simple to setup a dymanic proxy in linux with a single line command `ssh -D your_proxy_port -p your_remote_ssh_port username@remote_host_name`